# Failed to import python library in android studio?

Tags: python, android-studio, chaquopy

My android project (Kotlin) needs python library that is inside a python project with other utils packages. When I imported it and opened it in Visual Studio Code everything is working, but when I put the same project inside android studio, it can't find any imported python modules. I am using Chaquo library to run python script.
My python version: 3.10.6.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the [Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-studio-plugin):

> Chaquopy isn’t integrated with this plugin, so you’ll see the warning “No Python interpreter configured for the module”, and your code will probably display many error indicators such as “Unresolved reference” and “No module named”. These are harmless: just go ahead and run your app, and if there really is an error, the details will be displayed in the [Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

If you haven't already, you'll also need to list the library in the [`pip` block](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements) of your build.gradle file.